# impdp table with blobs from expdp dump

Tags: oracle12c, impdp, expdp, oracle-dump

Can someone here help me with impdp syntax to import a table with a different name in the same schema or a different schema (trying to make a copy of an existing table with BLOBS).

I was trying something similar to the below, but it didn't work.

```
impdp myschema/pwd directory=TEST_DIR DUMPFILE=myschema.dmp logfile=impdp.log  TABLES=mytable  REMAP_TABLE=mytable:mytable_test
```

And by the way, I tried the below too but fails with temp cannot extend...

```
create table myschema.mytable_test as select * from myschema.mytable;
```

Thanks

Comment: Just saying it didn't work isn't very helpful; what happened? What errors did you get on the command line or in the log?

Comment: thanks for suggesting, I have updated the import error log as well please have a look.

Comment: `IMAGE_TEST` seems to already exist; I see that you said to append to it, but it is valid to do so - is it actually a table (not a view etc.), does the definition match? I'm not sure it's actually valid to remap and append at the same time, don't think I've ever tried to do that. I'd see if it works when that object does not already exist - up to you if you want to drop it, rename it, or pick a different name for the remapping for now.

Comment: tried using the above updated command but it fails...